# Pass DOM element values to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX, HTML and PHP all together to provide a seamless experience to the user. I'm having trouble passing the variable to the PHP form right now. It's a little complicated the way I went about it, I'm not sure if there is an easier way as this is my first experiment with AJAX.

To explain in detail:

```
<div class="block" id="articles"></div>
```

I have this division which loads the details and loads the article. Inside of this division I'm trying to allow the user to add comments relating to the article.

```
function viewDets(str) {
  if(str == "") {
    document.getElementById("articles").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("articles").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "viewDets.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Using this is passes the variable to viewDets which then adds another container:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $count++;
    $taskComments = $row['Annotation'];
    $userName = $row['Username'];
    $timeStamp = $row['Time'];
    echo "Comments";
    echo "<p class=\"meta\">$count. $taskComments ($userName) -- $timeStamp</p>";
}
echo "</div></div></div></div></div></div>

<form name=\"inputCom\" method=\"get\">
    <div class=\"four column\">
        <div class=\"column_content\" id=\"commentInsert\">
            <label>Enter Comment</label>
            <input type=\"text\" id=\"comment\"value=\"\"></input>
            <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"Uname\" value=\"$user\"></input>
            <input type=\"hidden\" id = \"taskID\" name=\"taskID\" value=\"$q\" />                                                            
            <button type=\"button\" id = \"commentSub\" onClick=\"insertComm(comment, Uname, taskID)\" />Enter Comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>";
```

The name of this division is commentInsert and I've set up the AJAX so that on click, it should push the variables to a PHP function that inserts into my database for comments.

The issue that I'm running into is that I can't get the comment to pass to that PHP function.

```
function insertComm(str, uname, id) {
  insertC();

  if(str == "") {
    document.getElementById("commentInsert").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("commentInsert").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "subCom.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
```

I have been playing around with this function by trying to call things like document.getElementByID and calling that function as insertC(); but with or without the insertC() function I am still having issue passing the 3 variables in the Javascript function to the PHP function, I tried it with just one variable and I still have trouble getting it to pass.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: So much code, can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Good to see someone who is trying to learn JavaScript without the influence of jQuery.

Comment: yeah, I know it's a lot of code, so I was trying to walkthrough the mindset that I was in, so the first part is working everything from viewDets loads like it should. The insertComm script is the tricky one because I'm basically trying to read from a container that is inserted from viewDets.

Comment: Have you tried `str.value` instead of `str` from within `insertComm()`?

Comment: you actually support IE6 still?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `onClick=\"insertComm(comment, Uname, taskID)\"` assumes that these 3 variables are automatically set based on id.  They are not.
Instead, you need to read them from the DOM, for example:

```
var str = document.getElementById("comment").value;
var uname = document.getElementById("Uname").value;
var id = document.getElementById("taskID").value;
```

If you add these to the start of `insertComm`, then you won't need to bother passing in the arguments.

If you want your PHP script to have access to all 3 of these, you'll need to pass in `uname` and `id` as well as `str` when sending your request to `subCom.php`.  Note: it's best practice to encode these parameters using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), in case the user inserts unexpected characters (like &) which may mess up your request.

Comment: So they are!  Though they're set to the DOM element, not the value it seems.  
I'd be hesitant to rely on these - though perhaps that's just because I prefer to add event listeners in JS, rather than using on* attributes.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a very good practice to rely on such behaviour as is using inline event listeners :)

Answer (score 0):

```
... onClick=\"insertComm(comment, Uname, taskID)\" ...
```

When the button is clicked, `comment`, `Uname` and `taskID` are resolved by `document` because you're using inline code; although this really shouldn't be relied upon, it works like this:

```
comment = document.getElementById('comment');
// etc
```

As such, your function `insertComm()` is called with DOM elements instead of actual strings. To use them inside your function you would use `comment.value` for instance:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "subCom.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(str.value), true);
```

Also note that I'm using `encodeURIComponent()` to prevent malformed URL's caused by spaces in the string value for example.

However, it would be considered better if you would pass the identifiers in the HTML like this:

```
... onClick=\"insertComm('comment', 'Uname', 'taskID')\" ...
```

And inside your `insertComm()`:

```
var str = document.getElementById(comment).value;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "subCom.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);
```